# Can you explain the ultimate relationship between model and controller in yii?

Tags: php, yii

I am new to MVC pattern. I googled, wrote code snipped, played with lot of code. But still confused about the ultimate relationship between controller and model.
Before MVC my programming style was something like this.

```
class Users extend Database{
function __construct(){}
 public $id,$name;
 public function Save(){
   $this->Execute("[Built query using the two member variables]");
 }
}
```

And I used to use this class in my HTML as

```
$user = new User();
$user->id= "u1";
$user->name = "sarah";
$user->Save();
```

So, How can I bind my old understanding with yii model - controller thing?

**My Exact Confusion:**

1)When I create model for a table from the command i didn't find any property definition in the model for each column of the table. Instead in the controller this line is found `$model->attributes = $_POST['Message']` what the hell is this line?

```
Isn't it better this way:
$model->message = "hi";
$model->date ="10-10-2011";
$model->save();
```

Comment: I liked the MVC Song and it also helped me understanding the pattern :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYvOGPMLVDo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well to understand the single line

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['Message'];
```

we have to look into the model class. in model class (extends CActiveRecord, usually auto generated by gii) we have two functions of importance, attributeLabels and rules.

The attributeLabels lists all the models properties (or variables, or the columns we want to store in database, or simply attributes).

In rules function we have all the rules set for each and every variable/column/attribute.
In autogenerated form, these rules directly reflect our database structure, and in some cases we don't have a rule so just written the line

```
array('name', 'safe'),
```

This rule indicates that no rule is applied and it's safa to save the variable in database.

Now when in controller (or anywhere) when we have a $_POST['Message'] and we apply the single line

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['Message'];
```

All our posted values are applied to $model, i.e. we don't to go through each and every attribute/properties' validation and assignment and after just the single line

```
$model->save();
```

everything is get saved to database after validation. That's the beauty of using Model (CActiveRecord in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = new User();
$user->id= "u1";
$user->name = "sarah";
$user->Save();
```

Now that code you should write in controller action, and this

```
<span><?php echo $user->name ?></span>
```

Is your view.

Answer (score -1):

Thats what Active Record is for, what you have there, is the model's logic, there is no logic there that you should put in the controller, read about the [active record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)